# Могу ли я получить статус код в случае успешной операции при использовании синхронных или Observable запросов в Retrofit?

Tags: android, http, retrofit, rxjava

Могу ли я получить статус код в случае успешной операции при использовании синхронных или Observable запросов в Retrofit?

`@GET("/ip")
Ip getIp();`

или

`@GET("/ip")
Observable<Ip> getIp();`

Comment: Таких возможностей там нет. Возможно, будет, в следующей версии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая возможность будет в Retrofit v2.

Сегодня вышла первая бета версия.

Answer (score 2):

Для получения кода ответа:

```
Observable<Response<Ip>> getIp();
```

Далее, например, в `onNext()`

```
@Override
public void onNext(Response<Ip> ipResponse) {
  ipResponse.code()
  ...
}
```